# Having an issue with inline UL sizing/positioning

Tags: css, uinavigationbar, background-image

ok, so developing a site for one of my friend's church using wordpress and I've run into a snag. I dont normally get all fancy with the nav bar, but I decided to take a swing at it... so here's what I'm doing:

nav bar background is a 1x64 pixel repeat-x. nav bar is actually a UL inline display. I want to have the background of each `<li>` tag be a static set image butted up next to each other for dynamic awesomeness. the problem: I cant force the background image to its full 100%. it is only as wide as the text is. The image size (made in photoshop) is 167x64 pixels. I cant center the links inside the `<nav>` tag horizontally and cannot get the `<li>` background the full size it's supposed to be. I've tried manually setting the height on everything in each level to be 64px as well as using `verticle-align:middle;` for the positioning I want and it's just really messing with my head @.@

site located at http://parnell.co/hurricane-church-of-god

page source:

```
<div class="nav-wrapper">

            <!-- Nav -->

                <nav>
                    <ul id="menu-nav-bar" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-6 current_page_item menu-item-18"><a href="http://parnell.co/hurricane-church-of-god/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-19"><a href="http://parnell.co/hurricane-church-of-god/sample-page">Sample Page</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-17"><a href="http://parnell.co/hurricane-church-of-god/blog">Blog</a></li>
</ul>                </nav>

            <!-- /Nav -->

            <br class="clear">

        </div>
        <!-- /nav-wrapper -->
```

CSS Source:

```
/******************************************************
     *                    Navigation                      *
     ******************************************************/

    div.nav-wrapper {
        margin-top:-16px;
        -moz-border-radius: 15px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        background:url(img/nav-bg.png) repeat-x;
        height:64px;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }

    div.nav-wrappter ul,
    nav ul li {
        float:left;
        height:64px;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }

    nav ul#menu-nav-bar li {
        display: inline;
        list-style-type: none;
        vertical-align:middle;
        background-image:url(img/nav-button.png);
        background-size:100%;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        height:64px;
    }

    nav ul#menu-nav-bar li a {
        text-decoration:none;
        height:64px;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

Please bear with my sloppiness in code, i've been trying to wrap my head around it all day and have more or less started from scratch on that one part like 8 times. Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated

Comment: May not have any bearing on your question but I noticed this in the process of trying to figure out your problem: 404 Not Found - http://parnell.co/css/general.css"

Comment: I don't even know where to start. You have a typo, 'wrappter' instead of 'wrapper'. You will probably need to set a width on your li class. You should look at how to center text in css, text-align will mostly work for your centering horizontally, this site for vertically: http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/  Be careful with the negative margins. Do some serious css education, it will make your css cleaner and easier to read. I don't have time right now to resolve your issue. Maybe later tonight.

Comment: @ahillman3: css is located at http://parnell.co/hurricane-church-of-god/wp-content/themes/Hurricane-CoG/style.css   the installation of wordpress sees http://parnell.co/hurricane-church-of-god/ as the root of the domain. its my sandbox.

I realize there are probably several typos and sloppy code. As soon as I figure out what's working, I'll clean it up a lot and refine. It's been a long time since I've messed with web dev and especially CSS.  I'll take a look at the link you provided. thanks for the reply!

Comment: got the answer... I'll post it as soon as I can. dont have the rep to answer my own for a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks to @ahillman3, I was able to get my mind straight and figure it out. Great link btw. As well the typo... that was about the biggest issue because nothing would have worked right until that was fixed.  Specifying the width for the `<li>` tag forced the buttons to behave correctly. And as for centering the text, the css attribute `display:block;` when applied to `nav ul#menu-nav-bar li a {}` was the key to making the `<a>` tag (a line object) behave like a `div` or table (a block object). after that, it was as simple as adding some margin to get the text center in the box.

thanks guys!

Comment: Looks much better, glad I could help with limited time.